# What are valid reasons for a developer to leave a backdoor? Can they avoid keeping one?

Tags: security

Is there any sensible reason for a developer to make a backdoor and leave there after deployment? A lot of devs say they can't avoid keeping one. Is this true?

Comment: Btw I think this question might be better suited for [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

There are reasons to create backdoors but keep in mind that not every backdoor is planned and fixing backdoors might be difficult.

For example, a developer could create a backdoor in order to get access to the system later(in production).

Also, devs may be forced to create a backdoor due to a national security letter. Either they create a backdoor (for the NSA) and don't tell anybody or they stop developing the software(or go to jail).

Comment: Can't they remove the backdoor later after making it?

Comment: I already wrote that in my answer. They could but they may need it(first reason in my answer) or are not allowed to(second reason)